# Timer Routine to Auto close database doesn't always kick off

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a routine that works perfectly as long as the timer routine kicks off.  If it doesn't start, nothing happens.

1. A Hidden form called `frm_Invisible` gets loaded when my main form opens. My main form is a typical main form with buttons that open other forms.  It's not a switchboard.  I used to call `frm_Invisible` in the `On Load` event and not sure if it has made any difference but right now I put the call in the `On Open` event.

   The `frmMain` calls it like this:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
       DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Invisible", acNormal, , , , acHidden
   End Sub
   ```
2. `frm_Invisible` has an `On Timer` event:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Timer()
       Static OldControlName As String
       Static OldFormName As String
       Static ExpiredTime

       Dim ActiveControlName As String
       Dim ActiveFormName As String
       Dim ExpiredMinutes
       Dim CountDown

       On Error Resume Next

       ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
       ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

       Me.txtActiveForm = ActiveFormName

       If (OldControlName = "") Or (OldFormName = "") _
           Or (ActiveFormName <> OldFormName) _
           Or (ActiveControlName <> OldControlName) Then

           OldControlName = ActiveControlName
           OldFormName = ActiveFormName

           ExpiredTime = 0
       Else
           ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval
       End If

       'Timer interval is set to 1000 which is equal to 1 second
       'for testing, you can remove the /60 and make ExpiredMinutes happen a lot faster
       'otherwise, keep the /60 and it will truly be whatever you set at the end

       ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000) / 60
       Me.txtIdleTime = ExpiredMinutes
       Form_frmMain.txtExpiredMinutes = ExpiredMinutes

       If ExpiredMinutes >= 3 Then  ' Can change this to 3 if you remove the '/60
           'Opening this form will trigger the final count down
           DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAutoClose"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. If the time runs out I open a 3rd form that counts down from 20, giving the user a chance to keep the database open.

It merely counts down from 20 and runs

```
DoCmd.quit
```

unless the user clicks a button before the count down finishes.  That button just closes the 3rd form, preventing the database from closing.

To test the routine, I put a textbox on `frmMain`, so that I could monitor if the timer gets kicked off.

```
Form_frmMain.txtExpiredMinutes = ExpiredMinutes
```

Most of the time, it does and I can see the time counting. However, there are instances that I cannot account for why the timer doesn't start. So I haven't published this latest update for my users.

Comment: Timer doesn't start or `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAutoClose"` is not reached? put `debug.print "Timer started", now()` straight after `Sub Form_Timer()` to see if it's getting called and then you can work your way to the error source. Plus move your module level variables to module level.

Comment: I realized that the user may simply open the database and not even click anything, in which case would result in the timer not starting.  So I decided just to start with the  Else part of my If statement:
        ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval  because if the user does something, the If part will reset it to zero.  But now I get the run-time error 2474 the expression you entered requires the control to be in the active window.  Incidentally how do you format comments (like this one) to have the gray for code?  I can only do that with an initial post or answer.

Comment: Regarding your last question: That can be done using back-ticks (`\``) around it.

Comment: `MsgBox "Thank you"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just give you some general advice for now:

1. You should kick out `On Error Resume Next` to see if there maybe occures any error.
   Later on you should add 'correct' error handling.
2. Add a type to this variables: `ExpiredTime` and `ExpiredMinutes`. Maybe `Long`?
3. Variable `CountDown` isn't used at all.
4. To prevent overflows you could directly store seconds instead of milliseconds in your variable `ExpiredTime`.

Then see what happens.

**Update:**

Since it can happen in your scenario that no form and therefore no control can be active, I would create two procedures to retrieve that information.
Both just return an empty string in case error 2474/2475 occurs.

```
Public Function GetActiveFormName() As String
    On Error GoTo Catch

    GetActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

Done:
    Exit Function

Catch:
    If Err.Number <> 2475 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "GetActiveFormName()"
    End If
    Resume Done
End Function

Public Function GetActiveControlName() As String
    On Error GoTo Catch

    GetActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name

Done:
    Exit Function

Catch:
    If Err.Number <> 2474 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "GetActiveFormName()"
    End If
    Resume Done
End Function
```

Comment: Progress:  After removing On Error Resume next, I get run-time error '2474'

The expression you entered requires the control to be in the active window


I receive an error on line 35

ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name.

Comment: Thank you.  Nice and clean. I appreciate the 'Done:'  'Catch:'  from 'Try-Catch' in .NET -- don't know what's taken me forever to do the same in VBA.